How to implement a forward declared opaque type in global fragment?
I'm trying to migrate my library to c++20 module. My library provide C interface with some opaque type. Consider following code:
// abc.h
typedef struct ABC *ABC_PTR:

// abc_impl.h
#include "abc.h"
struct ABC {
    void func() {}
};

Previously, I can just implement the opaque type in another header.
But this won't work if I implement it inside a module, like this:
module;
#include "abc.h"
export module abc:decl;
struct ABC {
    void func() {}
};

I know that I can just keep the implementation in a header. But currently, I have a type that inherit another type already belongs to a module, and I cannot import a module in a header.
// def.cpp
export module def;
export struct DEF {};

// abc.h
typedef struct ABC *ABC_PTR:

// abc_impl.h
#include "abc.h"
import def; // this won't work // yes, this will work
struct ABC : public DEF { // DEF not found

};

So how can I deal with this problem? Does it mean I have to move DEF back to header?

It seems that I've met another problem but not this. Actually we can import module inside global fragment, and I'm not sure why I failed to do so before.

export module abc:decl; declares a module partition. Presuming it is relevant, what is the code for the corresponding module interface file, i.e., the file that contains the declaration: export module abc;? Are there other partitions?

actually partition doesn't matter much. it's fine to treat it as export module abc.
